# How to build libargp library with arm-linux-androideabi-gcc compiler in Linux OS

Tags: android, c, gcc, build-process, configure

I want to build the libargp library with arm-linux-androideabi-gcc compiler, but I can't to do it.

libargp is available from: https://github.com/alexreg/libargp.

I run the following commands to run the configure script with success:
$ libtoolize --force
$ aclocal
$ autoheader
$ automake --force-missing --add-missing
$ autoconf
$ autoreconf --install

. By the way, libargp can to be built with gcc, with success, by "build" script file use.
But I want to build it with arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.

So, I tried to change the "build" script file with the following contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

source ./common

if [[ ! -d "$BUILD_DIR/" ]] ; then mkdir "$BUILD_DIR/" ; fi &&

cd "$BUILD_DIR" &&
"../$GNULIB_DIR/configure CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc LD=arm-linux-androideabi-ld \
AR=arm-linux-androideabi-ar --host=arm-linux-androideabi" &&
make clean &&
make &&

exit 0 # EX_OK
```

, but if I try to execute this "build" script file, then I get the following error:
./build: line 9: ../gnulib/configure CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc LD=arm-linux-androideabi-ld AR=arm-linux-androideabi-ar --host=arm-linux-androideabi: No such file or directory
.

By the way, I don't know how to fix this error.

Thanks for any help.

Best Regards,
dsfb.

Answer (score 1):

In the parameters you are passing to configure, only "--host=arm-linux-androideabi" is valid. CC/AR/LD are environment variables and not arguments to configure. You should try like

```
CC=abc AR=xyz ./configure --host=foooo
```

In addition you will also need to specify SYSROOT to avoid picking up host libraries.